# Is it possible to display Android notifications with the absolute date?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am displaying the system notifications right now using `notificationBuilder.setShowWhen(true)` and `notificationBuilder.setWhen(millis)`. But when the time is recent I get the relative date format like on the screenshot.

Is it possible to always display the date in the absolute format like "hh:mm"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is part of the system-supplied UI. Developers cannot control it. How it renders (relative/absolute, etc.) will vary by OS version and may vary by device model (if manufacturers tweaked how notifications render).